# Failed to register serviceWorker on my site

Tags: node.js, reactjs, service-worker

I need the service worker to work on my site. I want the `PUBLIC_URL` to my sites url, service worker is not registering. It's working fine on localhost. And about the code it's the usual serviceworker that comes with `create-react-app` bundle.

This is for NodeJS,ReactJS and react-scripts of version @1.0.7.

This is the error:-

```
Error during service worker registration: DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker.The origin of the provided scriptURL ('https://s0Sdchq.ssls.com') does not match the current origin ('https://mysite1256.firebaseapp.com').
```